# Shading in XNA Game Studio

Tags: xna

I am looking to add the ability to draw shading into a project I am working on. Basically I need to replicate shading that appears on the bottom and right part of a frame border. I have added a reference to it below.

[image: Shading Example]

Has anyone got any knowledge on how to achieve this sort of shading? I have never dealt with this form of shading before.

Comment: Maybe you should explain a bit more in detail, what you're looking for. I've done a lot in XNA but I really don't understand your question.

Comment: you can create shading by multiplying same sprite with some offset and opacity behind original... if that's what you think...